# Instantiating class with template parameter at runtime (C++)?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to instantiate a class with a template parameter at runtime in the following way?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
  vector<T> d;
};

template<typename T>
struct Solver {
  Foo<T> data;

  virtual void calc() = 0;
};

struct SolverA : Solver<int>
{
  void calc() 
  {
    cout << "PRINT A\n";
  }
};

struct SolverB : Solver<double>
{
  void calc() 
  {
    cout << "PRINT B\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  ... solver;

  if (...) {
    solver = new SolverA;
  } else {
    solver = new SolverB;
  }

  solver->calc();
}
```

So classes `SolverA` and `SolverB` has no template parameter, but which one just be used cannot be decide at compile time. I tried to used `boost::any` for this, but I was not sure how to cast than the variable `solver` to call the function `calc()`. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a interface for your class :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
  vector<T> d;
};

struct SolverIface
{
  virtual void calc() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Solver : SolverIface {
  Foo<T> data;
};

struct SolverA : Solver<int>
{
  void calc()
  {
    cout << "PRINT A\n";
  }
};

struct SolverB : Solver<double>
{
  void calc()
  {
    cout << "PRINT B\n";
  }
};

int main()
{
  SolverIface *solver;

  if (0) {
    solver = new SolverA;
  } else {
    solver = new SolverB;
  }

  solver->calc();
}
```

Templates and virtual dispatch do not go along.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore oh well. and you moved Foo into solvers (which is even better) :)

Comment: Great! For this simple example is works. I'll go back to my working code and try the same thing there.

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't, nor there should be, because `SolverA` and `SolverB` are **completely unrelated types**. They have different base classes.

What you can do is:

```
struct SolverInterface
{
  virtual void calc() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Solver : SolverInterface {
  Foo<T> data;
};


int main()
{
   SolverInterface* solver;
   if (...) {
      solver = new SolverA;
   } else {
      solver = new SolverB;
   }
   solver->calc();
}
```